# What does comparing the result of the three-way comparison operator with nullptr do?

Tags: c++, c++20, nullptr, spaceship-operator

Given the example from [cppreference on `<=>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons), we can simplify the example code to:

```
struct person {
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;

    auto operator <=> (const person& p) const {
        if (const auto result = name <=> p.name; result != 0) {
            return result;
        } else {
            return surname <=> p.surname;
        }
    }
};
```

But my IDE (CLion 2020.2), via clang-tidy, warns that `result != 0` should actually be `result != nullptr`. I didn't know that we can compare `std::###_ordering` with `nullptr`. Cpprefence also [claims that we should rather compare it with literal `0`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/strong_ordering#Comparisons). There is nothing about `nullptr` there.

This code:

```
int main() {
    person p1{"ccc", "vvv"};
    person p2{"aaa", "zzz"};

    std::cout << (p1 < p2);
}
```

compiles (GCC 10.1.0, Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) and yields identical results to both the `0` and the `nullptr` version.

---

However, my IDE also warns me that I should "*Clang-Tidy: Use nullptr*" with `p1 < p2`. By applying the "fix", the code changes to `std::cout << (p1 nullptr p2);` which, well, doesn't compile. It hints that it may be a bug in clang-tidy, but it doesn't explain why we can compare the orderings with `nullptr`. Why we can, why does it work and why would we want that?

Comment: There's not a single mention of `nullptr` in your posted code..

Comment: Your IDE is not a C++ compiler. Only an actual compiler can fully understand C++ code. Especially the newer versions of C++. It is not surprising that an IDE misparses C++ code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl "*and yields identical results to both the `0` and the `nullptr` version.*" - I meant that if we actually replace `if (const auto result = name <=> p.name; result != 0)` with `if (const auto result = name <=> p.name; result != nullptr)`, the code compiles and yields the expected results.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, The error comes from clang-tidy (which still isn't a compiler, but it's pretty close where it matters). The IDE is simply handling the task of running clang-tidy and conveying the results.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik an actualy compiler (g++ 10.1.0) accepted and successfully compiled the code with `nullptr` instead of `0`. Barry covered the topic in his answer pretty well. It's not about parsing, it's about clang-tidy and actualy compilers (suggesting) and accepting this.

Comment: clang-tidy is also not a C++ compiler. It borrows some code from a C++ compiler, but it is not a complete C++ compiler, in of itself.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: "*clang-tidy is also not a C++ compiler. It borrows some code from a C++ compiler, but it is not a complete C++ compiler, in of itself.*" I don't know what that has to do with this issue. Clang-tidy is not saying that the code won't compile or is invalid or even broken; it's offering suggestions as to what it thinks is a better way to write that code. That's kind of it's job; it's definitely wrong in this case, but that is what it's trying to do.

Comment: As for "old" `operator <`, `auto operator <=> (const person& p) const { return std::tie(name, surname) <=> std::tie(p.name, p.surname); )` :) (or even `= default;` here ;) )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But my IDE (CLion 2020.2), via clang-tidy, warns that `result != 0` should actually be `result != nullptr`.

This is wrong. It should be `result != 0`. The comparison categories are specified to only be comparable against the *literal* `0`.

The check likely comes from the fact that the only real way to implement comparing against the literal `0` in C++20 is to take an argument whose type is some unspecified pointer or function pointer to pointer to member - and clang-tidy likely flags any `0` that you provide as an argument to a pointer as something that *should* be `nullptr`. Most of the time, this is correct. Just not specifically here. And indeed, if you write `result != nullptr` it probably will compile - but that's wrong and you should not do it.

This is a clang-tidy problem, it needs to understand that for comparison categories, it should not flag the use of literal 0 in this way.

Comment: So it seems like an implementation detail that fooled clang-tidy. Thanks, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Similarly, `virtual void foo() = nullptr;` is also _no bueno_.

Comment: @Eljay Sure, but that's not really the same thing - that's the grammar requiring `0` while this is more or less an implementation hack.